# Clarification needed on LookAt matrix calculation in DX9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I am going trough these 2 methods to calculate the lookat matrix

1. [D3DXMatrixLookAtLH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/d3dxmatrixlookatlh)

zaxis = normal(At - Eye)

xaxis = normal(cross(Up, zaxis))

yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis)

xaxis.x           yaxis.x           zaxis.x          0

xaxis.y           yaxis.y           zaxis.y          0

xaxis.z           yaxis.z           zaxis.z          0

-dot(xaxis, eye)  -dot(yaxis, eye)  -dot(zaxis, eye)  1

2. [D3DXMatrixLookAtRH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/d3dxmatrixlookatrh)

zaxis = normal(Eye - At)

xaxis = normal(cross(Up, zaxis))

yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis)

xaxis.x           yaxis.x           zaxis.x          0

xaxis.y           yaxis.y           zaxis.y          0

xaxis.z           yaxis.z           zaxis.z          0

dot(xaxis, eye)   dot(yaxis, eye)   dot(zaxis, eye)  1

why is the translation for RH not multiplied by -1?

Comment: THe RH version uses ``Eye - At`` instead of ``At - Eye`` for the zdir and the dot products are negated for the position to place them correctly. The only difference between LH and RH viewing coordinates is the z-axis direction.

Comment: Note that D3DX9 is deprecated as is legacy Direct3D 9. For new projects you should look at [DirectXMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath) which is all inline code instead of being hidden inside a DLL. There you'll see all that RH does is negate the view vector and then call the LH function.

Comment: If the issue is only with negation for Z axis, why should all the coordinates be inverted in the translation? wouldn't it suffice to just invert the translation in Z component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The Microsoft Doc page for `D3DXMatrixLookAtRH` is wrong. I've filed a [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/pull/857) to fix it.

In the actual implementation of D3DXMath, it's clear that in both cases the Translation should be `-dot(xaxis, eye)  -dot(yaxis, eye)  -dot(zaxis, eye)` for both LH & RH.

The *only* difference is the *zaxis* computation.

```
D3DXMATRIX* WINAPI D3DXMatrixLookAtRH
    ( D3DXMATRIX *pOut, const D3DXVECTOR3 *pEye, const D3DXVECTOR3 *pAt,
      const D3DXVECTOR3 *pUp )
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 XAxis, YAxis, ZAxis;

    // Compute direction of gaze. (-Z)
    D3DXVec3Subtract(&ZAxis, pEye, pAt);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&ZAxis, &ZAxis);

    // Compute orthogonal axes from cross product of gaze and pUp vector.
    D3DXVec3Cross(&XAxis, pUp, &ZAxis);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&XAxis, &XAxis);
    D3DXVec3Cross(&YAxis, &ZAxis, &XAxis);

    // Set rotation and translate by pEye
    pOut->_11 = XAxis.x;
    pOut->_21 = XAxis.y;
    pOut->_31 = XAxis.z;
    pOut->_41 = -D3DXVec3Dot(&XAxis, pEye);

    pOut->_12 = YAxis.x;
    pOut->_22 = YAxis.y;
    pOut->_32 = YAxis.z;
    pOut->_42 = -D3DXVec3Dot(&YAxis, pEye);

    pOut->_13 = ZAxis.x;
    pOut->_23 = ZAxis.y;
    pOut->_33 = ZAxis.z;
    pOut->_43 = -D3DXVec3Dot(&ZAxis, pEye);

    pOut->_14 = 0.0f;
    pOut->_24 = 0.0f;
    pOut->_34 = 0.0f;
    pOut->_44 = 1.0f;


    return pOut;
}

D3DXMATRIX* WINAPI D3DXMatrixLookAtLH
    ( D3DXMATRIX *pOut, const D3DXVECTOR3 *pEye, const D3DXVECTOR3 *pAt,
      const D3DXVECTOR3 *pUp )
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 XAxis, YAxis, ZAxis;

    // Compute direction of gaze. (+Z)
    D3DXVec3Subtract(&ZAxis, pAt, pEye);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&ZAxis, &ZAxis);

    // Compute orthogonal axes from cross product of gaze and pUp vector.
    D3DXVec3Cross(&XAxis, pUp, &ZAxis);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&XAxis, &XAxis);
    D3DXVec3Cross(&YAxis, &ZAxis, &XAxis);

    // Set rotation and translate by pEye
    pOut->_11 = XAxis.x;
    pOut->_21 = XAxis.y;
    pOut->_31 = XAxis.z;
    pOut->_41 = -D3DXVec3Dot(&XAxis, pEye);

    pOut->_12 = YAxis.x;
    pOut->_22 = YAxis.y;
    pOut->_32 = YAxis.z;
    pOut->_42 = -D3DXVec3Dot(&YAxis, pEye);

    pOut->_13 = ZAxis.x;
    pOut->_23 = ZAxis.y;
    pOut->_33 = ZAxis.z;
    pOut->_43 = -D3DXVec3Dot(&ZAxis, pEye);

    pOut->_14 = 0.0f;
    pOut->_24 = 0.0f;
    pOut->_34 = 0.0f;
    pOut->_44 = 1.0f;

    return pOut;
}
```

> Both `D3DXMatrixLookAtRH` and `D3DXMatrixLookAtLH` are part of "D3DXMath", the math library included in D3DX9 the D3DX10. These helper libraries are deprecated as is the DirectX SDK itself. The recommendation is to use [DirectXMath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/directxmath-portal) instead.

> If you must use D3DX9 for some reason, note you can avoid all the complicated issues covered on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) mixing the legacy DirectX SDK and modern versions of Visual Studio by just using the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX/) NuGet instead. New projects should move to any of the [various replacements](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/). See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/) for more details.